# HTTP Basic Auth Upon Image View (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, http, authentication, .htpasswd

I saw this and I'd love to know how to recreate it. Unfortunately, I don't know .htaccess.

Upon viewing an image, there was an HTTP Basic Auth style dialog that asked to enter some sort of authentication (albeit nothing actually submitted anywhere).

I'm sorry for the skid question, but I'd really love some insight as to how this can be done using .htaccess or .htpasswd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache site conf, add something like:

```
Alias /image /path/to/img
 <Directory "/path/to/img">
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "LoginImage"
     AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
  </Directory>
```

Then, create the .htpasswd file with:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd someusername
```

and you'll be prompted to create a password.